# Чим відрізняються кілька та декілька; кількоро та скількоро?

Tags: синоніми, числівники

Чи є якась відмінність у сенсі слів у парах: кілька та декілька; кількоро та скількоро?

Comment: -1: Це запитання виглядає недоопрацьованим; завжди варто демонструвати власну спробу відповісти і пояснення, чим знайдені варіанти не підходять. Це убезпечить інших користувачів від вгадування «що мав на увазі автор». Окрім того, варто надавати власні означення діалектних та рідковживаних слів; я не одразу зрозумів, що таке *кількоро*.

Comment: [Там](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/26421/) я також помітив і мінуснув. :)

Comment: Мовби зелений поїзд
Привидівсь і зник тепер:
Може, я сів у нього,
Віконце собі протер;
Може, дивлюся й дивлюся,
І, може, все впізнаю:
Тонко тремтить стеблинка
Над рейкою, на краю.
Може, то я, маленький,
Може, то ти... не руш...
Може, усіх, хто нас любить —
Горсточка, кількаро душ...

Сядемо в тихе човенце,
Стиснемо плечі до пліч,
Сонечка візьмемо в серце,
З ним — перебудемо ніч.
Може, не вмерзнемо в кризі,
Може, не згубим весла,
Може, в байдужій вітчизні
зЗайдемо дрібку тепла...

https://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/5348209.html

Comment: Кількоро взагалі вперше чую

Comment: Колись в школі нас вчителька пояснювала так, що кілька це означення до 10 шт, а декілька все, що більше 10 шт.
Але підтвердження цього не знайшла.Проте в моїй голові це закарбувалося

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Доктор філологічних наук Олександр Пономарів [відповідає](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/04/150428_ponomariv_blog54_ko):

> Чи є відмінність між словами **кілька** і **декілька**?
>
> Немає. Обидва ці числівники вживані на позначення невеликої кількости,
>   від трьох до десяти. Наприклад: "***Кілька*** парубків скочило до танцю,
>   потягши за собою дівчат" (Михайло Коцюбинський). "*Вже стояли **декілька**
>   возів із зерном*" (Панас Мирний).
>
> Але перевагу потрібно віддавати слову **кілька**. Воно коротше і входить
>   до складу таких утворень: **кілька**десят, **кілька**надцять, **кілька**денний,
>   **кілька**тижневий, **кілька**річний тощо. **Декілька** такої словотвірної
>   продуктивности не має.

Кількоро - розмовний [синонім](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE)

> **КІ́ЛЬКО́РО**, кілько́х, числ. неознач.-кільк., збірн., розм. Те саме, що
>   **кі́лька**. *Довкола огню сиділо кількоро людей, малих і великих* (Фр.,
>   II, 1950, 29); *Кількоро рук шанобливо вмочають у махорці пальці* (Кач.,
>   II, 1958, 182).

Скількоро - теж [синонім](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE), але діалектний.

> **СКІ́ЛЬКОРО**, числ. неознач.-кільк., діал. **Декілька**. *Та вийшло скількоро
>   чоловіка копати буряки* (Сл. Гр.).

Comment: Скрипін каже що різниця є :)

Comment: Я сюди теж потрапив після Скрипіна. У його визначенні декілька — це кілька десятків. Цікава інтерпритація.

Comment: @DimaZheludko, я не зовсім розумію, про які матеріали Скрипіна Ви кажете. Якщо він логічно обґрунтовує свою позицію або ж є поважним мовознавцем, то ми будемо раді, якщо Ви представите його позицію окремою відповіддю.

Comment: Якщо слова мають різний набір букв, то переважно є різниця. Дуже рідко, коли немає.

Answer (score 4):

#### Словники

> [КІ́ЛЬКА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) - Невизначена мала кількість (у межах від трьох до
>   десяти).
>
> [Де](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5) (частка, що вживається в неозначених прислівниках і
>   займенниках типу де́кілька, де́коли «іноді», де́котрий, [деоди́н]
>   «декілька» Ж, де́хто, де́що, де́який); - результат видозміни
>   просторової семантики питально-неозначеного прислівника де у виразах з
>   первісним значенням «десь котрийсь», «десь хтось» і подібне.
>
> [ДЕ́КІЛЬКА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0) - Невелика, незначна кількість; кілька.
>
> [kilkoro](https://translate.google.com.ua/#view=home&op=translate&sl=pl&tl=uk&text=kilkoro) - польською кілька.

#### Кожна буква має значення

Як бачимо зі словника різниця є. Якщо в слові кілька має місце лише кількість, то в слові декілька також вказують на невизначеність в місці і часі. Тобто:

- кілька возів - якесь невелике число возів;
- декілька возів - десь якесь невелике число возів.

Наприклад:

> Вже стояли декілька возів з зерном, з сіллю, рибою, декілька стільців
>   перекупок. (Панас Мирний)

Можна читати так: десь кілька возів з зерном, а десь кілька стільців перекупок.

#### Я теж маю слово

Якщо розглянути думку, що слова `декілька` не існує як єдиного цілого, або ж як вказано тут

> [Декілька такої словотвірної продуктивности не має.](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/04/150428_ponomariv_blog54_ko)

То з попереднього прикладу про вози, мабуть, правильніше "де кілька" писати окремо. І це може бути логічнішим. Якщо думка була такою:

> Вже стояли десь кілька возів з зерном, з сіллю, рибою, а десь кілька стільців перекупок. (вже не Панас Мирний)

Тобто,  якщо вважати, що під час написання `декілька` зробили помилку і забули вказати пробіл.

Заміну де на десь беру з тексту вказаного в словнику.

Comment: І в чому різниця між "кілька" і "десь кілька" (або "якесь" і "десь якесь")? _Update: А, я зрозумів, то Ви вважаєте, що "декілька" позначає не лише кількість, а й (невідомі) місце/час? Ну тоді перепрошую, але я з Вами незгоден._

Comment: @Sasha Так це ви не зі мною повинні бути не згодні, а зі словником. Так в словнику написано.

Comment: @Sasha Я вже звик, що тут бездоказово ставлять мінуси та не беруть до уваги докази чи логічні аргументи і під час цього не вказують аргументів проти. Я теж так деколи роблю.

Comment: чи не могли б розширити цитати Пономаріва? Бо не зрозуміло про, що йдеться, а відповіді мають бути якогомога закінченішими, тобто за можливості не вимагати переходу на інші ресурси.

Comment: @Yola Можете задати запитання по наявному тексту? Що ви не зрозуміли?

Comment: @Sasha З чим не згодні і чому?

Comment: Я не зрозумів, що це за думка після *Якщо розглянути цю думку:*? Про що вона?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, з тим, що невизначеність, задавана префіксом "де-", (з якогось дива) стосується місця/часу, а не кількості. "Де-" означає невизначеність саме за тією ознакою, на яку посилається корінь ("хто" -- "дехто (невідомо хто)", "чий" -- "дечий (невідомо чий)", "скільки" -- "дес̶кільки̶а (невідомо скільки)"). Ані в "дехто", ані в "дечий" префікс "де-" не стосується місця/часу.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, а також (це стосується оновленої відповіді), що "декілька" логічніше писати окремо (хіба що Ви всі інші слова на "де-" теж пропонуєте писати окремо).

Comment: @Sasha Кілька вже є Невизначена мала кількість. Для чого додавати де? З вашої логіки цю невизначеність підсилюють? Чому ви вирішили, що де- додає невизначеності? В словнику вказують на те, що первісним значенням до дехто є десь хтось. Не кажуть, що невідомо хто. Мова йде не лише про хто, але ще й про де.

Comment: @Sasha "хіба що Ви всі інші слова на "де-" теж пропонуєте писати окремо" - я не стверджую, а описую можливість.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, _*колк_ (перепрошую, не пам'ятаю точне написання) початково означало і "скільки", і "кілька". У деяких народів воно (або похідне слово) досі має два значення, у деяких має лише значення "скільки". Можливо, значення "скільки" колись було основним. А де-, відповідно, щоб позначити, що це не питання, а невизначеність (_*кто_ -> дехто, _*колк_ -> _декілька_).

Comment: Те, що ми зараз значення "скільки" позначаємо окремим словом _скільки_, дозволило "вивільнити" слово _кілька_ суто для значення "кілька" й використовувати його недвозначно, але колись це, імовірно, було не так (я припускаю, що колись _кілька_ було щонайменше двозначним, а щонайбільше його основним значенням було саме "скільки", а не "кілька" -- тому й з'явилися окремі слова _декілька_ (умовно: десь кілька) і _скілька_ (умовно: зо кілька) для позначення невизначеної кількості).

Comment: Загалом, слід ураховувати, що мова (будь-яка) не завжди ідеальним шляхом розвивається, є рудименти абощо.

Comment: @Sasha Ви можете дати джерела, на основі який ви зробили свої висновки?

Comment: _'*колк... початково означало і "скільки", і "кілька". У деяких народів воно (або похідне слово) досі має два значення, у деяких має лише значення "скільки"'_ -- це з ЕСУМ. Решта -- суто мої припущення, можливо, помилкові.

Comment: Мінусую допоки не приберете посилання на новинні ресурси, які не є авторитетним джерелом.

Answer (score 0):

Як уже зазначено тут, тлумачїння — подають як [Романа?] Скрипіна, що взагалї не єʼ мовознавцем — *кілька — до десяти, декілька — від десяти* є хибним. Тут можна побачити яскравий приклад явища як [нарідна етѵмолоґія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F), де, так розумію: *де* схоже на *десять*, а тому тут щось маʼ бути з десятками. На жаль, щось схоже можна побачити і [тут](/a/7353/585) від *Roman*-а [*Mikhol*](/users/2207/)-а: *де* в *дехто* і *де* — в подальшому, аби не уточнювати, писатиʼму як *de* — в *деколонізація* мають однаковий запис, а тому єʼ звязок.

Хоча в жодному випадку звязка немаʼ або не відповідаєʼ дійсʼностї. По перше, [*де-*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5#5080) в словах як *дехто* походить від *десь*, що веде до індоевропського слова [**kʷú-dʰe*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/k%D1%8Ade). Для порівняння, [*десять*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C#5225) від [*déḱm̥*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%C3%A9%E1%B8%B1m%CC%A5), тому жодного звязку. А наявність слів як *дехто* і — як зазначено тут і словами Пономарьова — *кількадесят*, *кільканадцять* — лише погіршують таку арґументацію. З другим випадком просто збіг: оба *де* і [*de*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5-), якщо геть грубо, походять від [**kʷ-*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/k%CA%B7%C3%ADs). Але на цїм все, бо від цего слова походять неймовірна куча слів і морфем, достатньо згадати: *хто* і саме ж *кілька*. Але від того, що слова мають одного далекого корня, не станемо однозначно казати, що всї вони тотожні. Так і тут, префікс *de-* означає «відокремлення, рух донизу, позбавлення, відсутність» — жодне значїння не підходить до *дехто*.

Ще один нѵянс, котрого чомусь тут ніхто не згадав: схоже, тут відбулася заміна [*нї*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/n%C4%9B-) [*нѣкъто*, *нѣчьто*, *нѣкыи*] — не плутати з [*ні*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/nik%D1%8Ato) [*никъто*, *ничьто*, *никыи*, *ничии*] — на *де* і це суто українська штука. Це не єдина заміна такого роду, можна зустрїти наприклад і *не-* як в [*некільки*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8#9838), що повністю тотожнє сучасному *декілька*. Як причину можна побачити в тому, що *неозначені* і *заперечні* займенники почали вимовлятися однаково. Особливо, гадаю, для місцин, де різниця вимови між *нї* і *ні* відсутня, що також затвердилося в сучасній стандартній українській.

Тож якщо керуватися чистою лоґікою і порівняннєм до слів як *декотрий*, *дехто*, *деколи* ітд, то *декілька* — неозначений займенник, коли *кілька* — [питально-відносний](http://linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/zaimen/zaimvid.htm). Але це не спрацьовуєʼ, бо *кілька* — не питальне і не відносне, хоча можна якось натянути, особливо через *скільки*, але наразї це не відповідаєʼ дійсʼностї і навіщо? До означального теж не додати, бо цю поведінку вже маєʼ [*стільки*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8). Тому це більше схоже до [катеґорій слів](//iul-nasu.org.ua/pdf/ukrmova/2_18/8.pdf) як *кількоро* ~ *скількоро*, *відти* ~ *звідти*, *оба* ~ *обидва* ітд. Тобто коли [спрощується](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) чи навпаки ускладнюється структура слова без огляду на семантіку певних морфем. Українська тут далеко не особлива, можна згадати поширену анґлійську: *about* [складається](//etymonline.com/search?q=about) з *a* + *by* + *out*, але можливе спрощеннє в [*ʼbout*](//urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%27bout), *because* → [*ʼcause*](//english.stackexchange.com/a/250267/226239) попри існуючого окремого слова *cause* ітд. Тож недивно, що узусно і за словниками, цї слова зазвичай позначаються як сѵнонѵмами.

Щодо правопису, то зараз, звісно, вони записуються разом. Але гісторії відомий запис і через дефіс — і це не поодинокий випадок.

- [На теми дня.](//zbruc.eu/node/105794) (К. Білокриниченко, 1921): *де-який*, *де-які*, *якого-сь*;
- [Ревизор](//shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Hohol/Revyzor_vyd_1918.pdf) (Переклав М. Садовський, 1918): *де-які*, *де-хто*, *де-що*, *де-кілька*, *якого-сь*;
- [Галичина й Україна в листуванні 1862—1884 р.р.](//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9._%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B9_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%96_1862%E2%80%941884_%D1%80.%D1%80._%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BC_I._1931.pdf) (К. Студинський): *де-що* (*де-чого*, і *де-шчо*), *де-якихъ* (*де-якими*, *де-які*), *де-инде* (тут від [*де*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5), а не *десь*, але зараз *деінде* при *де-небудь*), *де-хто* (*де-кому*), *де-где* (за контекстом схоже на *десь*);
- [Материяли до українсько-руської етнольоґії](//archive.org/details/etnologia/) (за редакцією Хв. Вовка, 1899): *де-який* (*де-які*), *де-коли*, *де-що*…
- ітд.

Answer (score -1):

## ДЕКІЛЬКА

> **§ 44.2 Частки**
>
> Разом пишемо словотворчі частки ***аби-*, *ані-***, **де-**, ***чи-*, *що-*, *як-*** **у складі слів**,
> **належних до будь-якої частини мови**: *аби́що, аби́як*; *аніскі́льки, анітро́хи, анія́к*; *деда́лі, де́коли, де́котрий, де́що*; *чимале́нький, чима́ло*; *щове́чора, щогоди́ни, щоде́нник,
> щодня́ , щодоби́* , *щоду́ху, щонайкра́щий, щопра́вда*,
> *щора́зу, щоси́ли; якнайшви́дше, якомо́га* та ін.;

---

> **§ 114. Складні займенники (неозначені й заперечні)**
>
> Займенники, до складу яких входять частки **аби-**, **де-**, **ні-**,
> **-ся**, **-небудь**.
>
> **Примітка.** [Займенникові числівники](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/Pravopys.2019/ukr.pravopys-2019.pdf) ***де́кілька*, *кіл́ька***, *скі́льки*, *сті́льки* відмінюємо як числівник ***два***: ***де́кілько́х*, *де́кілько́м***, ***де́кількома́***; *бага́то* відмінюємо так: *бага́то*,
> *багатьо́х*, *багатьо́м*, *багатьма́* й *багатьома́* .

---

Роль префікса у процесі словотворення дуже важлива. Префікси розширюють словниковий запас мови та виражають різні нюанси значення. В українській мові існує близько 100 префіксів, які використовуються для словотворення і граматичних функцій. Близько 20 з них є запозиченими (*а-, анти-, гіпер-, **де-**, інтер-, квазі-* та ін.)

[Етимологія](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de-#Latin) префікса **de-** (**укр. де-**) уходить корінням ще до латинської мови.

Префікси грецького та латинського походження: **a-/an-, anti-, de-, dis-/dys-, exo-, ecto-, endo-, hyper-, hypo-, ana-, apo-** використовуються при утворені спеціальних термінів. Відповідно до семантичних ознак та функцій префіксів, а також співвідносних з ними похідних основ усі префікси можна поділити на три групи: префікси на означення антонімічних (протилежних) понять, на означення інтенсивності ознаки або неповноти ознаки. Префіксальний спосіб творення нових термінів характеризується приєднанням префіксів, що несуть різне смислове навантаження. Головну семантичну роль у цьому типі термінотворення відіграють префікси, основною рисою значеннєвої структури яких є функційно-семантична спеціалізація. Вищенаведені префікси використовуються власне для означення протилежних понять. Треба звернути увагу на те, що деякі префікси з вищенаведеного ряду є синонімічними по відношенню до власне українських префіксів.

> На позначення відсутності чогось при деривації медичних термінів
> вживається [префікс **de-**](https://science.lpnu.ua/uk/terminologiya/vsi-vypusky/visnyk-no-709-2011/greko-latynski-prefiksy-ta-yih-vidobrazhennya-v), який має варіативні значення протилежності
> та застосовується:
>
> а) на позначення ліквідації, знищення: *decorticatio, demarcatio,
> defecatio, desinfectio*;
>
> б) на позначення порушення, розладу (аналогічне значення в
> синонімічному префіксі **дез-**: *degeneratio, decompressio,
> dehydratatio, deformatio* тощо. Також зі значенням порушення, розладу
> вживається префікс **dys-**: *dysuria, dyskinesia, dysmenorrhoea,
> dyspepsia, dysplasia, dyspnoe, dystonia, dystrophia,
> dysphagia,dysfunctio*.

---

Отже, на мою думку, на відміну від слова **кілька**, яке позначає невизначену кількість, слово **декілька** в українській мові частіше вживають на позначення кількості, яку можливо перелічити.

Наприклад:

1. Як вести облік товарних запасів ФОПу, яка здійснює діяльність у декількох місцях продажу?
2. Якщо запитання має декілька правильних відповідей, надайте всі правильні відповіді.
3. Так звані надходження до місцевих бюджетів можна розділити на декілька джерел.

Comment: Гмм, бачу, Роман дуже любить латину і натягувати під єю українську, де звязку взагалі немаʼ [це тут]. Бо це вже [неуперше](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/6742/585) [або звязок не як «старший ~ молодший»].

Comment: Може, якщо ви маєте краще пояснення або можете заперечити щодо походження частки де-, то долучайтеся

Comment: Це ви маїте довести чи підкрїпити думку, що це _де-_ в _декілька_ тотожнє до латінського _де-_ як в _декомунізація_. Я такого тут не бачу, але ви подали, що воно так і є. Краще поясненнє [вже наводили](https://goroh.pp.ua/Етимологія/де#5080) тут: це від _десь_, що в свою чергу від _де_ (як в _де ти був?_).

Comment: @Sútnôstj, Де- в "де ти був" - це взагалі прислівник на позначення місця/напрямку. 1. Мій допис створено, щоб спростувати думку user1677 - слово "декілька" пишеться разом. 2. Етимологія де- як раз вказує на походження.

Comment: 1.  _Мій допис створено, щоб спростувати думку user1677 - слово "декілька" пишеться разом._ — Не указує, тут про «Префікси грецького та латинського походження», чим «де-» в «декілька» не є.

Comment: 2. _Етимологія де- як раз вказує на походження._ — Ніде не бачу. Так, указує на походження латинського префікса *де-*, котрий **нічим не повʼязаний** з українським непрефіксом *де-*. Тобто, повторюся: ніде не бачу, але бачу як особа дуже любить вчергове примазувати латину до української, коли на тої потреби взагалі немаʼ.

Comment: @Sútnôstj, Чому, на вашу думку, префікс де- не може виключати з "кілька" неозначеність , тобто уточнювати, так само як "десь кілька"?