# Походження слова "море"

Tags: етимологія

Чи має відношення до англійського "more"? (ще більше води?)

навіяно питанням у [німецькому se](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/65868)

Comment: Було би непогано, якби а) трохи дослїдили від себе, б) сюди перенесли суть і отримане з ланки Нїмецького SEʼа.

Comment: @stegetsj Питання на німецькому SE не дуже корисне, бо там значення слів "море" і "озеро" звучать подібно до датської, але ніби помінялися місцями.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Море** походить від латинського **Mare**

Наприклад, [**Чорне море**](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk&ie=UTF-8&sl=auto&tl=uk&text=Mare%20Nigrum%0A&op=translate) на середньовічних зображеннях, взятих з давньоримських мап позначається [Mare Nigrum](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tabula_Geographica_Qua_Pars_Russiae_Magnae_Pontus_Euxinus_seu_Mare_Nigrum_et_Tartaria_Minor.jpg).

[image: Чорне море]

[Походження слова Море](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5)

**Мо́ре**. Загальнослов'янське. Споріднене з нім. Meer «море», лат. mare — те саме, готськ. marei — тж., нім. Moor «болото».

[Етимологія слова Море](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5)

**МО́РЕ** «великий водний простір»

- іє. *ḿori «море, болото»;
- споріднене з лит. mãrios (mãrė) «море, затока», лтс. mare «затока», гот. marei «море», двн. mari, дангл. mere, нвн. Meer, дірл. muir, лат. mare «тс.», з іншим ступенем чергування голосного двн. muor «калюжа, болото», дангл. mōr «калюжа», нвн. Moor «болото»;
- псл. morje «водний простір; море»;
  р. мо́ре «море; [озеро]», бр. мо́ре, др. море, п. morze, ч. moře, слц. more, вл. mоrjo, болр. море́, м. море, схв. мȍре, мȏре, слн. mórjé, стсл. море;

До англійського **more** українське **море** геть не має відношення. **More** - це порівняльний ступінь від **many** (багато). **many** - **more** - **most**

Comment: Всї можуть помиляти ся, але вага наукового погляду важливіша, за пихатьків, котрі вивчили декілька мов і гадають, же вже розбирають ся ві всьому, при цьому не наводять жодних прикладів, котрі варті уваги.

Comment: **Підсумуємо:** мапа і ґуґл не є джерелами, пак 100 %-м, походження слова. Джерелами є визнані працї або етимолоґічні словники. Тож згадані словники кажуть про _споріднення з_, а не _походження від_ латини, тобто підсумок — брехливий. Якщо не розумієте що таке спорідненість, то пояснюю — коли вони мають одного корня роду, тобто, якщо грубо, такі собі (дво-)брат і сестра, а мати тут є ПІЄ. Одне джерело вже згадане в одному відповідї (моє), а друге стосувало ся радше московській мові супроти української. Про друге — некритично, але не дуже культурно.

Comment: Ах, забув додати до свойого **підсумка**. Ви кажете, же анґлійське _more_ і українське _море_ не мають звязку. Як довід наводите _тлумачно_ (причому без джерел), але, як я вже казав, так не доводять походження слів, бо слова самі по собі можуть зьмінювати своє значення.

Comment: @stegetsj якщо маєте приклади вжитку англ. "more" у значенні "море", наводьте їх будь ласка, будемо дискутувати. Основне запитання стосується походження слова і саме на нього давав відповідь. Якщо вважаєте, що окрім латини, існує інша мова, з якої «mare» могло потрапити в усі інші споріднені мови, то теж будь ласка наводьте приклади.

Comment: Ем… Схоже, ви не геть не вмієте чи не хочете читати. Повторю. Бо: 1) наведене вами джерело вже вказує походження слова _море_: іє (→ праслов.) → укр; тому і питаю, відки взяли, же укр. _море_ пішло від лат. _mare_? 2) запитання стосуєся не в походженні слова, а про спорідненість слів _море_ і _more_, тобто треба навести походження двох слів. 3) я вже навів ві своїй відповідї.

Comment: Но і аби довести до абсурда, може ви нарешті зрозумієте, чому несете маячню. Споріднене до українського слова _море_ [також](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/móri) є: осетинська _mal_ < _*mārya-_, санскрит मर्यादा _maryā́dā_. Тобто мови, котрі далекі від латини. Будь ласка, читайте джерела, котрі самі наводите, і робіть відповідні висновки, а не свої чи чиїсь безпідставні здогадки.

Answer (score 4):

- Анґлійське [*more*](//etymonline.com/word/more#etymonline_v_18358) → ПІЄ **meis-*, можливо від ПІЄ **me-* «великий». Словʼянський відповідник наче [відсутнїй](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary).
- Українське [*море*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5#12479) → ПІЄ **ḿori*. Ґерманські відповідники: гот. *marei* «море», двн. *mari*, дангл. [*mere*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*mori-), нвн. *Meer*, дірл. *muir*; з іншим ступенем чергування голосного двн. *muor* «калюжа, болото», дангл. *mōr* «калюжа», нвн. *Moor* «болото».

---

Коротко і наразї: **немає**.